# Writing a double sum as a function in R

Tags: r

[image]

I am attempting to write a double sum function as in the formula in the attached image. 
I'm trying to write the summation as a function of β()

Here's my attempt :

```
n0=10
lambda=0.5
n=50
alpha=0.05

f <- function(j,s,delta) {choose(n0,j)*choose(n-n0-1,s-1-j)*lambda^j*(1-lambda)^(n0-j)*(pnorm(delta-qnorm(1-lambda)))^(s-1-j)*(1-pnorm(delta-qnorm(1-lambda)))^(n-n0-s+j)}
g <- function(s,delta) {pnorm(delta-qnorm(alpha*(1-lambda)/(n-s+1)))*sum(sapply(0:s-1,f,s))}
sum(sapply(1:50,g))
```

I can't figure out how to do so.

When I compute the summation not as a function (without the delta):

```
f <- function(j,s) {choose(n0,j)*choose(n-n0-1,s-1-j)*lambda^j*(1-lambda)^(10-j)*(pnorm(qnorm(1-lambda)))^(s-1-j)*(1-pnorm(qnorm(1-lambda)))^(n-n0-s+j)}

g <- function(s) {pnorm(qnorm(alpha*(1-lambda)/(n-s+1)))*sum(sapply(0:s-1,f,s))}
sum(sapply(1:50,g))
```

everything seems fine

Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your definition of the `g` function, you need to pass `delta` as an explicit parameter to the `sum(sapply(0:s-1,f,s))` bit:

`sum(sapply(0:s-1,f,s, delta))`

so:

```
g <- function(s,delta) {pnorm(delta-qnorm(alpha*(1-lambda)/(n-s+1)))*sum(sapply(0:s-1,f,s,delta))}
```

Then you can run your overall sum by passing your desired delta into it:

```
delta <- 0.1
sum(sapply(1:50,g, delta))
```

Also, please note that you have a `10-j` in your `1-lambda` power expresson in `f` - that should be `n0 - j`?